# Scoping problems with decorators in inheritance

Tags: python, inheritance, decorator

I am trying to check if a class is capable of possessing a file through a decorator, using the code below I found out that even though sub class `CSVStorageHandler` calls its parent's `checkIfNoStorageHandler` the variable `func` is out of scope.

This is rather confusing, can anyone help out?

```
class StorageHandler(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.output_file = self.openFile()

    def checkIfNoStorageHandler(func):
        def createFileByStorageHandler(self, *args, **kwargs):
            print func
            if self.__class__.__name__ == "CSVStorageHandler":
                return self.func()
            else:
                print ("class " + self.__class__.__name__ + " don't store file by default")
                return None
        return createFileByStorageHandler

    @checkIfNoStorageHandler    
    def openFile(self):
        return open('./log.txt', 'w')

class CSVStorageHandler(StorageHandler):
    def doNothing(self):
        pass
class NoStorageHandler(StorageHandler):
    def doNothing(self):
        pass


test = CSVStorageHandler()
```

Error Message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tset_decorator_inheritance.py", line 27, in <module>
    test = CSVStorageHandler()
  File "tset_decorator_inheritance.py", line 3, in __init__
    self.output_file = self.openFile()
  File "tset_decorator_inheritance.py", line 9, in createFileByStorageHandler
    return self.func()
AttributeError: 'CSVStorageHandler' object has no attribute 'func'
```

Comment: I don't see anywhere where you assign a ``func`` attribute to ``StorageHandler`` or any of its children. So that error message makes total sense. It has nothing to do with scoping. Did you just mean to do ``return func()`` instead of ``return self.func()``?

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but `func()` is `openFile(self)` , I needed the `self.func()` for it to call correctly

Comment: See @Eevee's answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self.func()` is a valiant attempt, but doesn't work because dot syntax will never care about a local named `func`.

You want to make sure the function receives `self`, so just pass it in.

```
return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it worked, but what is the difference between `self.func()` vs `func(self)` , isn't it exactly the same thing, you are both just passing `self` to the function?

Comment: no; `self.func()` looks up `func` as a method on `self`.  `func(self)` passes `self` to a local or global function named `func`.  `self.func()` ultimately passes `self`, yes, but the primary thing it does is _find the function in the first place_.

Answer (score 0):

`func` is in scope, but your code is trying to access `self.func`. Maybe you mean to use `func()` instead of `self.func()` on line 9?